# Fill the gaps in Eulers proof of Fermats last theorem for n=3

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I wanted to read Euler's proof of Fermat's last theorem for n=3 but the versions I have found all seem to have a gap.  The key missing result is
$$ p^2 + 3q^2 = c^3=> p = r(r^2 + 3s^2),  q = 3r(r^2 - s^2) $$

*for some r,s assuming p,q relatively prime and c odd.*

Which is equivalent to the lemma below from a book by Edwards

*Let p and q be relatively prime numbers such that pp +3qq is a cube. Then there exist integers a and b such that $p+q\sqrt{-3} = (a+b\sqrt{−3})^3$*

It is clear from many of the proofs that if $p^2+3q^2 = c^3$ then $r^2+3s^2 = c$ for some r,s

From there it follows that

$$p^2 + 3q^2 = [r(r^2 + 3s^2)]^2 + 3*[3r(r^2 - s^2)]^2$$

But this result isn't sufficient to prove the necessary lemma.

[Dan Harmon's blog](http://fermatslasttheorem.blogspot.com/2005/05/fermats-last-theorem-n-3-key-lemma.html), gets this wrong, but apparently the error Euler made was similar, so he is in good company.

[This proof](https://www.whitman.edu/Documents/Academics/Mathematics/byerleco.pdf) acknowledges the gap, and provides a reference to a proof of the required lemma, but I don't have access to the book
*Edwards, Harold M.“Fermat’s Last Theorem: A Genetic Introduction
to Algebraic Number Theory.” Springer-Verlag. New York. 1977.*

[Euler wrote a paper](http://scholarlycommons.pacific.edu/euler-works/272) in latin that is said to fix the problem with his first proof, but I can't see that it does this.  I can't read latin though, so maybe google translate misled me

I found a copy of Euler's proof in German(I think) on p159 here,[Bergman](https://gdz.sub.uni-goettingen.de/id/PPN235181684_0164?tify=%7B%22pages%22:%5B32,33%5D,%22view%22:%22info%22%7D) but I can't read it.

Comment: Do you want to have the articles translated or the gap filled?

Comment: In https://gdz.sub.uni-goettingen.de/id/PPN235181684_0164?tify={%22pages%22:[177],%22panX%22:0.489,%22panY%22:0.816,%22view%22:%22scan%22,%22zoom%22:0.892} there is the german article by Bergman from page 159 on. There is the question discussed directly.

Comment: I found an english source as well, in which the German article is cited and the problem discussed: https://books.google.de/books?id=c6TTBwAAQBAJ&pg=PA39&lpg=PA39&dq=euler+fermat+bergman+translation&source=bl&ots=K7OMHzDP8U&sig=ACfU3U0oE1qZYCKPsVHcPxo2kHQmsOSrVw&hl=de&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwid-57M3OPtAhXS8uAKHfDtCs8Q6AEwA3oECAoQAQ#v=onepage&q=euler%20fermat%20bergman%20translation&f=false, which answers your question from page 39 on.

Comment: Is [this](http://fermatslasttheorem.blogspot.com/2005/05/fermats-last-theorem-proof-for-n3.html) acceptable?

Comment: Thsnks for your reply.  That is Dan Harmons blog which I referenced in the question.  He ignores the problem

Comment: Thanks for your detailed replies. The german article looked very interesting, but I do not know if it addresses the question or not. The second answer is to a book by Ribenboim, which is the best summary of n=3 that I have found. That is where I found the Bergman reference. Unfortunately he states the more difficult bits without proof, and cites Carmichael for the proofs. The third link is Dan Harmons blog which I referenced in the question. Harmon ignores the problem – Ralph 3 secs ago   Edit   Delete

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below are excerpts from H. M. Edwards, giving proof of the Lemma needed to close the gap in Euler's published proof of Fermat's Last Theorem for the case $n=3$.

"**Lemma.** *Let $a$ and $b$ be relatively prime numbers such that $a^2+3b^2$ is a cube.  Then there exist integers $p$ and $q$ such that $a+b\sqrt{-3}=(p+q\sqrt {-3})^3$*.

Proof.  Let $a^2+3b^2=P_1P_2...P_n$ be a factorization into $4$'s and odd primes as in **(4)**. If this factorization contains exactly $k$ factors of $4$ then $2^{2k}$ is the largest power of $2$ which divides $a^2+3b^2$ and, since $a^2+3b^2$ is a cube, it follows that $2k$ and hence $k$ are multiples of $3$. Moreover, any odd prime $P$ in the factorization must occur with a multiplicity which is a multiple of $3$. Thus $n$ is divisible by $3$ and the factors $P_1P_2...P_n$ can be arranged in such a way that $P_{3k+1}=P_{3k+2}=P_{3k+3}$. It follows that in the factorization of $a+b\sqrt{-3}$ given by **(3)** the factors corresponding to each group of three $P$'s are *identical* because the only choice is the choice of sign
$p^+_-q\sqrt{-3}$ and both signs cannot occur. Taking one factor from each group of three and multiplying them together then gives a number $(c+d\sqrt{-3})^3$ such that $a+b\sqrt{-3}={^+_-}(c+d\sqrt{-3})^3$. Since $-(c+d\sqrt{-3})^3=(-c-d\sqrt{-s})^3$ the desired result follows."

The Lemma evidently rests on some preliminaries since Edwards refers to results **(3)** and **(4)** in the course of his proof:

**(3)** "*Let $a$ and $b$ be relatively prime. Then $a+b\sqrt{-3}$ can be written in the form$$a+b\sqrt{-3}={^+_-}(p_1{^+_-}q_1\sqrt{-3})(p_2{^+_-}
q_2\sqrt{-3})\cdot\cdot\cdot(p_n{^+_-}{q_n}\sqrt{-3})$$where the $p$'s and $q$'s are positive integers and ${p_i}^2+3q_i^2$ is either $4$ or an odd prime*

If $a^2+3b^2$ is even then it is divisible by $4$. If $a^2+3b^2$ is not $1$ then it has factor $P$ equal to either $4$ or an odd prime and either **(1)** or **(2)** gives $a+b\sqrt{-3}=(p^+_-q\sqrt{-3})(u+v\sqrt{-3})$ where $p^2+3q^2=P$. Then $u$ and $v$ are relatively prime and the problem of taking a factor $p^+_-q\sqrt{-3}$ out of $u+v\sqrt{-3}$ is the same as that of taking one out of $a+b\sqrt{-3}$ except that $u^2+3v^2=(a^2+3b^2)/P$ is smaller than $a^2+3b^2$. Iterating this process must eventually lead to a stage $a+b\sqrt{-3}=(p_1{^+_-}{q_1}\sqrt{-3})\cdot\cdot\cdot(p_n{^+_-}{q_n}\sqrt{-3})(u+v\sqrt{-3})$ where $u^2+3v^2=1$. Then $u={^+_-1}$, $v=0$, $u+v\sqrt{-3}= {^+_-1}$ and the factorization is complete."

**(4)** "*Let $a$ and $b$ be relatively prime. Then the factors in the above factorization of $a+b\sqrt{-3}$ are completely determined, except for the choice of signs as indicated, by the fact that $({p_1}^2+3{q_1}^2)({p_2}^2+3{q_2})^2\cdot\cdot\cdot({p_n}^2+3{q_n}^2)=a^2+3b^2$ is a factorization of $a^2+3b^2$ into odd primes and $4$'s. Moreover, if the factor $p+q\sqrt{-3}$ occurs then the factor $p-q\sqrt{-3}$ does not, and conversely.* The thing to be proved in the first statement is that $p^2+3q^2=P$ determines $p$ and $q$, up to sign, if $p$ is $4$ or an odd prime. This is clear in the case $P=4$. If $P$ is an odd prime and if $a^2+3b^2$ were another representation of it then, by **(2)**,$$a+b\sqrt{-3}=(p^+_-q\sqrt{-3})(u+v\sqrt{-3})$$and $P=P(u^2+3v^2)$, that is, $u^2+3v^2=1$, $u={^+_-1}$, $v=0$, $a+b\sqrt{-3}={^+_-}(p^+_-q\sqrt{-3})$ as was to be shown. The second statement is simply the observation that $p+q\sqrt{-3}$ and $p-q\sqrt{-3}$ would combine to give a factor $p^2+3q^2$, which is impossible if $a$ and $b$ are relatively prime."

Since **(3)** and **(4)** above make reference to **(1)** and **(2)**, this lengthy citation of Edwards is not quite complete. I omit the proofs for now, but in **(1)** and **(2)** Edwards shows:

**(1)** "*If $a$ and $b$ are relatively prime and if $a^2+3b^2$ is even then $a+b\sqrt{-3}$ can be written in the form$$a+b\sqrt{-3}=(1^+_-\sqrt{-3})(u+v\sqrt{-3})$$where the sign is appropriately chosen and where $u$ and $v$ are integers."*

**(2)** "*If $a$ and $b$ are relatively prime and if $a^2+3b^2$ is divisible by the odd prime $P$ then $P$ can be written in the form $P=p^2+3q^2$ with $p$ and $q$ positive integers and $a+b\sqrt{-3}$ can be written in the form $a+b\sqrt{-3}=(p^+_-q\sqrt{-3})(u+v\sqrt{-3})$ where the sign is appropriately chosen and where $u$ and $v$ are integers."*

I hope this is of some use in filling the gap in question.